# In python, how to pass an array argument to powershell script

Tags: python, powershell

I have a PowerShell script,  which has two parameters,  the first one is a string, the second one is an array of string.

I would like to call this PowerShell script from my python code. How to pass the array type parameter to PowerShell?

If I write something like this:

```
subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', 'script.ps1', 'arg1', '@("str1", "str2")'])
```

Powershell think '@("str1", "str2")' is a string,  not an array.

**Edit**
I found a workaround

```
subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', 'script.ps1 arg1 @("str1", "str2")'])
```

It doesn't look beautiful, but works.  and in this way, I can't use `-File` after `powershell.exe`

Comment: To be clear: Your original command _does_ work as written (except that you must use `.\script.ps1` rather than `script.ps1`, unless the script is in the system's path), as long as you use `-Command` rather than `-File`; With `powershell.exe`, `-Command` is _implied_. Caveat: With `pwsh.exe` (PS Core), `-File` is implied.

Answer (score 5):

**Your original command *does* work as written** (except that you must use `.\script.ps1` rather than `script.ps1`, unless the script is in the system's path), as does the second one you added later, **because it implicitly uses the PowerShell CLI's `-Command` parameter** rather than its
`-File` parameter.

In short:

- **Passing *arrays* is fundamentally only supported with `-Command`**, which **interprets the subsequent arguments *as PowerShell code***, where the usual PowerShell syntax applies.
- **With `-File`, by contrast, all arguments after the target-script argument are passed *verbatim***, as strings, so there is *no concept of an array*.

I suggest using the following approach, for increased robustness and conceptual clarity:

```
subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', '-noprofile', '-c', '.\script.ps1 arg1 @("str1", "str2")'])
```

<sup>Note: You can omit `@(...)` around the array elements - `@()` is never needed for array literals in PowerShell.</sup>

Note:

- `-noprofile` ensures that PowerShell doesn't load the `$PROFILE` file(s), which avoids potential slow-downs and side effects.
- `-c` (`-Command`) makes it explicit that you're passing *PowerShell code* rather than a *script file* with *literal arguments* (`-File`)

  - Do note that `-Command` arguments are subject to additional interpretation by PowerShell, so if you pass, say, a token `$foo$` you intend to be a literal, PowerShell will expand it to just `$` (if no `$foo` variable is defined), because it expands `$foo` as a variable reference; passing `` `$foo`$ `` (backtick-escaping) prevents that.
- Note the `.\` before `script.ps1`: Since you're using `-Command` you cannot execute a script by *file name only* (unless the script happens to be located in a directory listed in `$env:PATH`); as from inside PowerShell, executing scripts from the current directory requires `.\` for security reasons; by contrast, file-name-only invocation *does* work with `-File`.
- The script file as well as its arguments are passed as a *single* argument, which reflects how PowerShell will process the command.
- `-Command` is the default in *Windows PowerShell*, but no longer in PowerShell *Core* (`pwsh.exe`), which defaults to `-File`; it is generally a good idea to explicitly use `-Command` (`-c`) or `-File` (`-f`) to make it obvious how PowerShell will interpret the arguments.

---

#### How `subprocess.run()` builds the command line and how PowerShell parses it:

---

Your original Python command passes `@("str1", "str2")` as an *individual* argument to `subprocess.run()`:

> `subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', '.\script.ps1', 'arg1', '@("str1", "str2")'])`

This results in the following command line executed behind the scenes:

```
powershell.exe .\script.ps1 arg1 "@(\"str1\", \"str2\")"
```

Note how only `@("str1", "str2")` is double-quoted, and how the *embedded* `"` chars. are escaped as `\"`.

<sup>As an aside: PowerShell's *CLI* (arguments passed to `powershell.exe`) uses the customary `\`-escaping of literal `"` chars.; *inside* PowerShell, however, it is `` ` `` (backtick) that serves as the escape character.</sup>

---

Your second command combines the `script.ps1` and `@("str1", "str2")` into a *single* argument:

> `subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', '.\script.ps1 arg1 @("str1", "str2")'])`

This results in the following command line:

```
powershell.exe ".\script.ps1 arg1 @(\"str1\", \"str2\")"
```

Note how the single argument passed is double-quoted *as a whole*.

Generally, `subprocess.run()` *automatically* encloses a given argument in `"..."` (double quotes) if it *contains spaces*.

Independently, it escapes *embedded* (literal) `"` chars. as `\"`.

---

**Even though these command lines are obviously *different*, PowerShell's (implied) `-Command` logic processes them *the same***, because it uses the following algorithm:

- First, enclosing double quotes around each argument, if present, are *removed*.
- The resulting strings, if there are multiple, are concatenated with spaces.
- The resulting single string is then executed as PowerShell code.

If you apply this algorithm to *either* of the above command lines, PowerShell ends up executing the same code, namely:

```
.\script.ps1 arg1 @("str1", "str2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your python array is `arr`

try to do this:

```py
subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', 'script.ps1', 'arg1', '\"{}\"'.format(','.join(arr))])
```

To send array in powershell script you can send it as `"item1,item2,item3"`
and the function `str.join` allow you to get this format easly

If this doesn't work, i would try to edit the script to use the `$args` argument in the powershell script to change the way you using your arguments

Comment: As it turns out, there is no problem to solve, because the original command in the question works as-is (the OP presumably tried `-File` rather than the implied `-Command` first).  Slight caveat regarding your solution: the `.join()` call only works if all elements of `arr` are already strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes on the command line - e.g. `@('str1', 'str2')` or escape the double quotes with backslashes - e.g. `@(\"str1\", \"str2\")`

For example with this script:

**script.ps1**

```bsh
param( [string[]] $s )
write-host $s.GetType().FullName
write-host $s.Length
write-host ($s | fl * | out-string)
```

You can call it from a command prompt like this:

```
C:\> powershell.exe .\script.ps1 @('str1', 'str2')
System.String[]
2
str1
str2
```

or like this:

```
C:> powershell.exe .\script.ps1 @(\"str1\", \"str2\")
System.String[]
2
str1
str2
```

You might need to apply some python escape characters to get the desired result in your code though.